# LiteralImpl cannot be cast to class Resource (LiteralImpl and Resource are in unnamed module of loader 'app' (Jena)

Tags: java, spring, sparql, jena

I'm creating a web app (spring + react) that will query an endpoint (selected by the user) with a certain query. For the purposes of this app I'm using jena.

This is the method where I use jena:

```
@Override
public List<String> save(QueryDto queryDto) {
    Endpoint endpoint = endpointRepository.findById(queryDto.getEndpointId()).orElseThrow(() -> new EndpointNotFoundException(queryDto.getEndpointId()));
    List<String> list = new ArrayList();

  //  String prefix = "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>";
    Query query = new Query(queryDto.getName(),
            queryDto.getContent(),
            endpoint);

    RDFConnection conn = RDFConnectionFactory.connect(endpoint.getUrl());

    String subjectString = queryDto.getContent().split("\\?")[1].split(" ")[0];
    System.out.println("SUBJECT STRING" + subjectString);

    QueryExecution qExec = conn.query(queryDto.getContent()) ; //SELECT DISTINCT ?s where { [] a ?s } LIMIT 100

    ResultSet rs = qExec.execSelect() ;
    /*qExec.close() ;
    conn.close() ;*/
    while (rs.hasNext()) {

        //System.out.println(results.getResourceModel());
        //ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out,results, q);
        QuerySolution qs = rs.next();
        System.out.println("qs: "+qs);

        Resource subject = qs.getResource(subjectString) ;

        System.out.println("Subject: "+subject.toString()) ;
        list.add(subject.toString());
    }


    queryRepository.save(query);
    return list;
}
```

My app works for the following query: SELECT DISTINCT ?s where { [] a ?s } LIMIT 100
and the selected endpoint being: https://dbpedia.org/

However it doesn't work when I try to query a more complex query:

PREFIX dbr: http://dbpedia.org/resource/#
PREFIX dbo: http://dbpedia.org/ontology/#
select distinct ?birthName where {dbr:Woody_Allen dbo:birthName ?birthName} LIMIT 100
(the selected endpoint once again being https://dbpedia.org/)

I get the following exception:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.LiteralImpl cannot be cast to class org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Resource (org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.LiteralImpl and org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Resource are in unnamed module of loader 'app')] with root cause
> java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.LiteralImpl cannot be cast to class org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Resource (org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.LiteralImpl and org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Resource are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
> at org.apache.jena.sparql.core.QuerySolutionBase.getResource(QuerySolutionBase.java:38)
> at com.finki.sparql_tool_web_app.service.impl.QueryServiceImpl.save(QueryServiceImpl.java:86)
> at com.finki.sparql_tool_web_app.web.QueryController.save(QueryController.java:34)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

I have never gotten a similar exception and I couldn't find much about it online either. Any idea how to fix this issue?

If a little explanation of my code (and my app) is needed:

- I have an entity called Endpoint, that contains the name (ex: dbpedia) and url(ex: https://dbpedia.org/)
- I also have an entity called Query, that has a name (ex: Query1), content(ex: SELECT DISTINCT ?s where { [] a ?s } LIMIT 100) and the selected endpoint.
  I can show other parts of the app if any are needed for better understanding.

Edit: I tried the following queries as well and the app works fine for them:

PREFIX dbr: http://dbpedia.org/resource/
SELECT DISTINCT ?s where { [] a ?s } LIMIT 100

PREFIX dbr: http://dbpedia.org/resource/
SELECT DISTINCT ?s where { dbr:Woody_Allen a ?s } LIMIT 100

It is only when I add "dbo:birthName" instead of "a" that it throws an exception.

Comment: calling `getResource` obviously doesn't work for literals - that's also what the error message indicates. You have to distinguish in advance what kind of node the variable is, e.g. call `isResource` or `isLiteral` on the `RDFNode` object which you get via `get()` method - then you can - depending on the type - call the appropriate `getXXX` method or just cast via `asXXX` on the `RDFNode` object

Comment: The PREFIXs have "#" on the end - the DBpedia URIs don't use the # form.              `PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>` and same for `dbo:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Resource subject = qs.getResource(subjectString)`

A resource is a URI or a blank node, and is not a literal.  The query results include a literal (e.g. string).

Class `RDFNode` is the Jena class of all RDF terms that can occur.

The operation `QuerySolution.get(varname)` retrieves the RDFNode. The cdoe can then inspect the kind of RDF term

e.g.

```
         RDFNode rn = qs.get(subjectString) ;
         if (rn.isLiteral() ) { ... }
         else if (rn.isURIResource() ) { ... }
         else // other cases blank node would presumable be an error
```